# How to prevent an optional field from being validated in codeigniter 3.1.11

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm working on a project which uses CodeIgniter 3.1.11 version.

Currently, I'm working on a form where I need to validate all the fields in the form except one which is optional. I see CodeIgniter 3 is validating all the fields every time I'm submitting this form. Below is the code for my form.

```
<form action="/save_shipping_profile" method="POST" id="shipping_profile">

        <table cellPadding="15" width="100%">
            
            
            <tr>
                <td width="150">Address:</td>
                <td>
                    <input id="address" class="experian_address_autocomplete" type="text" name="address1" 
                    value="<?= $shippingInfo['shipping_address']; ?>" size="50" required /> 
                    <span class="required">*</span>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td width="150">Address 2<br /><span style="color:#a6a6a6;font-size:10px;">(Apt, Suite #, etc..)</span></td>
                <td><input id="address2" type="text" name="address2" value="<?= $shippingInfo['shipping_address2']; ?>" size="50" autocomplete="address-line2" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td width="150">City:</td>
                <td><input id="city" type="text" name="city" value="<?= $shippingInfo['shipping_city']; ?>" size="50" required autocomplete="address-level2" /> <span class="required">*</span></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td width="150">State / Province:</td>
                <td>
                        <input id="state" type="text" name="state" value="<?= $shippingInfo['shipping_state']; ?>" size="50" />";
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td width="150">Zip / Post Code:</td>
                <td><input id='zip' type="text" name="zip" value="<?= $shippingInfo['shipping_zip']; ?>" size="15" required autocomplete="postal-code" /> <span class="required">*</span></td>
            </tr>
            
            **<?php if ($site_options['show_phone_number_shipping_profile']): ?>
                <tr>
                    <td width="150">Phone Number:</td>
                    <td><input id='phone' type="tel" name="phone" value="<?= $shippingInfo['billing_phone']; ?>" size="15" autocomplete="phone-number" /></td>
                </tr>
            <?php endif; ?>**
            

            <tr>
                <td width="150">&nbsp;</td>
                <td><input id="save_shipping" type="submit" name="submit" value="Save Shipping Information" /></td>
            </tr>

        </table>
    </form>
```

Below is my controller file

```
    function save_shipping_profile()
    {
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
    
        $this->form_validation->set_message('address_check', 'The %s field may not be an address.');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('address1', 'Address', 'required|trim|xss_clean|callback_address_check');
      // $this->form_validation->set_rules('phone', 'Phone', 'permit_empty');
    
        if(!$this->form_validation->run())
        {
            $array = array();
            $array['error'] = '1';
            $array['message'] = validation_errors("- "," ");
    
        }
        else
        {
            // Execute the main code
        

        }
    }
```

I'm trying to skip the validation for the phone field. I've found in my research that in CodeIgniter 4, the below line would make the phone field optional but it's not working on CodeIgniter 3.1.11. I've researched various articles but not able to find any relevant answer for this. Can someone please suggest me about this ?

> $this->form_validation->set_rules('phone', 'Phone', 'permit_empty');

Can someone please help me with this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For more control don't use `->set_rules('field', 'label', 'rules')`. Use array:

```php
$config = [
  [
    'field' => '',
    'label' => '',
    'rules' => '',
  ],
  ...
];
$this->form_validation->set_rules($config);
```

So define your general array and when you use phone, just add it to array.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. After making the changes you said, I'm still getting the same error even after I define a $config array for more control

Comment: Are you use if statement to check, that you need to validate phone? You show phone input only when `$site_options['show_phone_number_shipping_profile'])` is true, so in controller before validating you need to add phone validation rule, if phone field is exist. And do not add it, when phone field isn't exist.

Comment: Yes, I tried that way too. The strange thing is that I'm getting an alert box with "Please enter your phone number" as error message even though the 'phone' field is not rendered on the page.

Comment: Can you show me your changed controller code?

Comment: This actually worked for me. Not sure what happened the first time but eventually it did work for me. Thank you for your advise.